# mostrar resultado url contenido por php

Tags: php, json, web

Tengo este enlace: https://servers-live.fivem.net/api/servers/single/5.189.142.172:30120

y lo que queria es sacar la informacion por medio de php y crear mi propio generador de servidores de gta v ,

¿Cómo se podria sacar esa informacion mediante php?

Espero haberme explicado bien

algo asi:
[image: Pero no me sale todo lo que quiero]

Pero no me sale todo lo que quiero

Gracias antemano!

Comment: Agrega que has intentado. Para mas información sobre preguntas que sean bien recibidas te recomiendo leer [ask] y como crear un [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://servers-live.fivem.net/api/servers/single/5.189.142.172:30120');
$obj = json_decode($json);

echo $obj->access_token;
```

Proba este codigo, si no te dejo un pagina de stack overflow pero en ingles.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617512/get-json-object-from-url